# sshd_config seems to ignore AuthorizedKeysFile directive

Tags: ssh-keys, sshd

I wan to stop users using ssh-copy-id to a server

In my sshd_config I have set

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/global_authorized_keys
```

I confirm it has been read by `sshd -T | grep -i authorizedkey`

```
authorizedkeysfile /etc/ssh/global_authorized_keys
```

I created a read only file to match

```
ls -l global_authorized_keys 
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 15 10:38 global_authorized_keys
```

The issue is when the sshd service has been restarted, a client can still use

```
ssh-copy-id client@server
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 2 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys

Number of key(s) added: 2

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'client@server'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

and when I check in the client .ssh directory I see

```
ls -l authorized_keys 
-rw------- 1 client client 1312 Sep 15 10:42 authorized_key
```

So it appears that sshd ignores the AuthorizedKeysFile directive?

My server version is

```
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
```

Perhaps also relevant is my use of LDAP as a provider of public keys for users

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey keyboard-interactive
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/local/bin/ldap-ssh-keys.sh %u
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

cat /usr/local/bin/ldap-ssh-keys.sh
#!/bin/bash

ldap_server="ldaps://server.example.com"
ldap_base="dc=example,dc=com"
#log_file="/var/log/ldap-ssh-keys.log"

# Get the public key from LDAP
search_output=$(ldapsearch -x -H $ldap_server -b "$ldap_base" -LLL "(uid=$1)" -o ldif-wrap=no sshPublicKey 2>&1)
#echo "$search_output" >> "$log_file"
public_key=$(echo "$search_output" | grep sshPublicKey:: | cut -d' ' -f2- | tr -d '\r\n' | base64 -d 2>&1)
#echo "LDAP returned SSH public key: $public_key" >> "$log_file"
logger -t ldap-ssh-keys "LDAP public key search for $1 at $ldap_base on $ldap_server found: $public_key"

# Output the public key if found, or nothing if not
echo "$public_key"
```

Supplementary to this, I have changed individual users authorized keys to be a link to the global set which is read only

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    31 Sep 15 11:15 authorized_keys -> /etc/ssh/global_authorized_keys
```

I have implemented the change to the LDAP script to Python with minor modifications

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import ldap
import ldap.filter
import syslog

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("username")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Use filter_format() to avoid LDAP filter injection
    filter_str = ldap.filter.filter_format("(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=%s))",
                                           [args.username])

    conn = ldap.initialize("ldaps://ldap.example.com")
    
    try:
        conn.simple_bind_s()

        res = conn.search_s("dc=example,dc=com",
                            ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                            filter_str,
                            ["sshPublicKey"])

        if len(res) == 0:
            syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_WARNING, f"No LDAP entry found for {args.username}")
            exit(2)
        elif len(res) > 1:
            syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ALERT, f"More than one LDAP entry for {args.username}")
            exit(1)

        for dn, attrs in res:
            keys = attrs.get("sshPublicKey", [])
            syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_INFO, f"Found {len(keys)} keys for {args.username}")
            for val in keys:
                syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_DEBUG, f"Found key: {val}")
                print(val.decode().strip())

    except ldap.LDAPError as e:
        syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, f"LDAP error: {e}")
        exit(3)
    finally:
        conn.unbind_s()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have a remaining issue that the LDAP script is called twice per connection

```
Sep 16 06:58:16 egde ldap-ssh-keys.py: Found 1 keys for jeremy
Sep 16 06:58:18 egde ldap-ssh-keys.py: Found 1 keys for jeremy
Sep 16 06:58:18 egde systemd[1]: Started Session 742 of user jeremy.
Sep 16 06:58:21 egde systemd[1]: session-742.scope: Succeeded.
```

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is when the sshd service has been restarted, a client can still use `ssh-copy-id`

ssh-copy-id is just a script that **manually** creates the file on the remote system and appends a line to it – it doesn't use any special sshd facilities to do so. (Not even to find out the correct path to append, as `sshd -T` is far too recent an addition).

So a client can use ssh-copy-id the same way that the client can use `vim ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and there's nothing that the sshd could really do to influence that.

The only thing that the option changes is whether sshd will *read* the file in question or whether it'll remain completely ignored. Your users can ssh-copy-id all they want, the SSH server simply will not accept logins using the keys they've uploaded.

---

Also, that LDAP script is bad. It assumes that there will be only one key (the 'sshPublicKey' attribute is multi-valued) and it assumes that ldapsearch will always output its value Base64-encoded (which it *does not,* unless the key's comment happens to have some non-ASCII text in it!). Do it properly.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import ldap
import ldap.filter
import syslog

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("username")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Use filter_format() or escape_filter_chars() to avoid LDAP filter injection
filter = ldap.filter.filter_format("(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=%s))",
                                   [args.username])

conn = ldap.initialize("ldaps://ldap.example.com")
conn.simple_bind_s()
res = conn.search_s("o=Example",
                    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                    filter,
                    ["sshPublicKey"])

if len(res) > 1:
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ALERT, f"More than one LDAP entry for {filter}")
    exit(1)

for dn, attrs in res:
    keys = attrs.get("sshPublicKey", [])
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_INFO, f"Found {len(keys)} keys for {args.username}")
    for val in keys:
        syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_DEBUG, f"Found key: {val}")
        print(val.decode().strip())
```

Comment: I have created a work-around by changing `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` into a root owned link to `/etc/ssh/global_authorized_keys` which is owned by root and is read-only